Do I need a transit visa for Paris (CDG) from Sri Lanka?
I am a Sri Lankan and Canadian temporary visa holder. Do I need a transit visa in Paris for a connecting flight to Montreal?


Aside: only 1 hour to transit at Montreal? If you are changing to a domestic flight, won't you have to go through immigration?

Have you read the French Goverment website Airport Transit Visa?

Thanks for your comments.
